# Melhorar inserção em banco de entidades relacionadas?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel-5

Tenho no banco de dados as tabelas **User**, **Profissional** e **Endereço**. A chave estrangeira de **User** está em **Profissional** e chave estrangeira de **Profissional** está em **Endereço**. Preciso cadastrar um profissional, que é um usuario e tem um endereço.

***Model User:***

```
public function profissional()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profissional', 'users_id');
}
```

***Model Profissional:***

```
public function endereco()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Endereco');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'users_id');
}
```

***Model Endereço:***

```
public function profissional()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Profissional');
}
```

A maneira que encontrei para inserir o profissional no banco juntamente com as outras entidades foi essa:

```
$user = new User($userData);
$profissional = new Profissional($profissionalData);
$endereco = new Endereco($enderecoData);

$user->save();
$user->profissional()->save($profissional);
$profissional->endereco()->save($endereco);
```

O código está funcionando normalmente, porém acredito que existam formas melhores de se fazer a mesma coisa. Gostaria de soluções alternativas ou melhorias que possam ser feitas nesse código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É assim mesmo como tu fez, pode ser feito para criar assim também:

```
$user->create(array())
     ->profissional()->create(array())
     ->endereco()->create(array());
```

mas, a lógica sua está dentro do padrão do [**Laravel**](http://www.laravel.com)